# Tried installing FastAi but I got "ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision>=0.7"

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai, torchvision

I tried installing Fast Ai using the command

```
pip install fastai
```

But then I got this error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision>=0.7 (from fastai) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.3.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision>=0.7 (from fastai)

What happened and how do I solve this? I tried installing some specific torch versions but none works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error just means that you are missing a required library of the given version `PyTorch>=0.7`.

As it states in the [Instructions](https://github.com/fastai/fastai#installing) if you installing it by using `pip` make sure to install `pytorch` manually to the required version. You can see [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) on instructions for installing `PyTorch`.